# Is "items[]size" a valid array declaration?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a foreach and inside it there's an input that has a name of `items[]size` and another input that has a name of `items[]price`. When I try to fetch their value it just returns an array of `items[]`. How do I get only the `items[]size` value or `items[]price` value?

```
@foreach($sizes as $size)
                <input type="checkbox" name="items[]size" value="{{ $size->id }}">
                <x-label>{{ $size->value }}</x-label>
                <input type="text" name="items[]prize">
                <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: There, I edited it, I'm using laravel.

Comment: did you try `item[][size]`?

Comment: It returned a multi dimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```html
@foreach($sizes as $size)
    <input type="checkbox" name="items[{{ $loop->index }}][size]" value="{{ $size->id }}">
    <x-label>{{ $size->value }}</x-label>
    <input type="text" name="items[{{ $loop->index }}][prize]">
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Oh man, after a day and a half of trying I finally got it to work the way I wanted, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ha ha. Glad I could help :)